# Belongs_to with where conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following situation:

A banner has 1 attachment which one has a lot of children (called attachments). Then I need to get the attachment and his children (what I already got). BUT I want only attachments (both parent and children) which have `mime_type == 'image. (jpg/jpeg)'` or any type of image.

**Model (working)**

```
class Admin::Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachment, -> { includes :attachments }, foreign_key: :admin_attachment_id, class_name: 'Admin::Attachment'        
    has_many :attachments, through: :attachment
end
```

I'm trying to get the attachments with that condition with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
belongs_to :attachment, -> { includes :attachments, where "mime_type REGEXP 'image.*'" }, foreign_key: :admin_attachment_id, class_name: 'Admin::Attachment'
```

Comment: You need to qualify which table the where clause applies to: `"attachments.mime_type REGEXP ? image.*"`

Comment: I did, I'm getting the following error `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ... includes :attachments, where "attachments.mime_type REGEXP ... ... ^`

Comment: @max any suggestion?

Comment: `includes(:attachments).where("...")`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: @max I know this statement, I can use it in controller, instead I want to put the `includes` in my model.

Comment: It actually hard to grasp what you're trying to do. "I have the following situation:A banner has 1 attachment which one has a lot of children (called attachments)"

Do you mean that each Banner has multiple attachments, one of which is the "parent", or do you mean that each attachment has children attachments?

Either way I feel like you may have got your modelling incorrect and should consider revising...

Comment: A banner has an unique attachment, BUT this attachment have multiple children.

Comment: Why you do not use scope like this: scope :images, -> { include(:attachments).where("...")}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with the following code:

```
class Admin::Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachment, -> { where "admin_attachments.mime_type REGEXP 'image.*'" }, foreign_key: :admin_attachment_id, class_name: 'Admin::Attachment'
    has_many :attachments, through: :attachment
end
```